# Apache rewrite rule for a destination containing a hash mark

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, fragment-identifier

I'm trying to issue a redirect where the destination contains a fragment-identifier part. 
I tried with this rule:

```
RewriteRule   ^/foo/bar/([^/]+)/(.*)$  /cgi/script#foobar::$1.$2  [R,L]
```

However the `#` is converted into `%23` and the web application cannot correctly parse this url. How can I force apache to keep the `#` character ?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Solution found: there is an option for not escaping urls with mod_rewrite:

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_ne

Adding the [NE] flag solved the problem.

Comment: Is there a way to *NOT* append the querystring? Using this method I get `/myUrl?123` redirecting to `/newUrl#hash?123`. I know there's the `QSA` flag, but I need to find the opposite.

Comment: @SimonEast You have the `QSD` flag on Apache 2.4. Or simply append a `?` on the end of the `RewriteRule` substitution.