# Redirection of full path containing hash

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I understand that the "#hash" isn't processed server-side, but I need to know if it's possible to make the client re-direct from this url:

```
http://domain.com/section/products/category/filter-category-1
```

to this one

```
http://domain.com/section/products#filter-category-1
```

So, the user access to the first URL and instantly goes to the second URL.

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9993017/apache-rewrite-rule-for-a-destination-containing-a-hash-mark

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it with php it is as simple as:

```
header('Location: http://domain.com/section/products#filter-category-1');
exit();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use htaccess (so you can add custom logic before or just after the redirect), you can just do:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/section/products/category/filter-category-1') {
    header('Location: http://domain.com/section/products#filter-category-1');
    die();
}
```

Place this in a .htaccess if you want to redirect with HTTP status 301

```
Redirect /section/products/category/filter-category-1 /section/products\#filter-category-1 [L]
```

Comment: The browser just throw a 404 error. I'm placing that code in `http://domain.com/section/products`

Comment: @JimmyAdaro you need to put it in whichever file is called when you visit the first URL, I'll amend my post to include the .htaccess option too, which seems to be the best option in your case.

Comment: But `http://domain.com/section/products/category/category-1
 ` doesn't exists. It's just a link for Google Adwords, which will be 301-redirected to `http://domain.com/section/products#filter-category-1`.

Comment: Edited my post, place `Redirect /section/products/category/filter-category-1 /section/products#filter-category-1 [L]` in a .htaccess file in /section/products and it should work.

Comment: That is throwing 500 error. Also, it should be `[L,R=301]`, right?

Comment: Escape the # character, some servers treat stuff differently, its working for me as is